# Why did value of string integer changed when putting it into int array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?");
    int x = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    int[] array = new int[x];
    
    System.out.println("Enter " + x + " integers, one per line:");
    Integer y = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    String z = y.toString();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = z.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(z.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

I put 1 to feed into the array and when I printed it, it got printed 49 instead.

Answer (score 3):

You put a `char` into an `int` array, and you got the expected result -- which is the ASCII value of the character `'1'`, [or 49](https://www.asciitable.com/).

What you want to do for your use case is to use `Integer.parseInt` on the `String` of the entire line, not to try to convert the individual characters.